# Where do we store the theme author info in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

when we design a theme for wordpress, where do we store the themename and author name. I am referring to theme name and link to authors site which is seen beside the themes on the admin console when we click the themes menu item in dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments in your theme's `style.css` file
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet